# What exactly happens when you get a "Trick" after clicking the pumpkin?

Tags: clicker-heroes

When you click the pumpkin that wanders over your screen fast enough, you will eventually get a treat or a trick. Treats are obvious, but what exactly happens if you get tricked?

I am unable to see any consequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **There is no consequence or any action whatsoever. The only punishment is that you don't get the treat.**

That pretty much sums it up. The wiki says:

> There was a chance of a pumpkin appearing on the screen. Clicking on this until it disappeared makes it give a "trick" or "treat". The treat is a random skill that is immediately activated, even if it hadn't been bought yet or was on cool down. (It does not affect the current status of that skill.) This can even activate The Dark Ritual. **Trick appears to do nothing.**

[Source](http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Holiday_Events)